# jQuery check length of field if a specific id

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm currently looping through a series of input boxes and performing
a validation if a user simply doesn't input anything. I've got a 
conditional that says if it is a specific id single that input box
out and do a seperate validation for it. It's a simple validation that
simply checks to make sure the length of the form is less than 10 characters. 
But for some reason it's not working. If I input a single character 
it just goes to the next iteration. Also is there anyway I can remove
having these multiple if statements inside of if statements.  Any 
help is greatly appreciated.

```
$("form :input").each(function(){ 

var $this = $(this);

if(!this.value.length){

    if(this.id == "phoneNumber" && $this.is(":visible")){
       if($this.val().length < 10){
         alert("phone number required");
       }
    }


} else if($(this).is(":visible")){
  //do some other validation    
}
```

Comment: And what `id` is it that you're trying to single out? The `phoneNumber`?

Comment: The [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested tests are the problem : there's no sense in testing if the length is `<10` when you already tested it's `0`. When the value is 1 char length, then you don't even check if it's too small as a phone number.

You probably wanted this :

```
if (this.id == "phoneNumber" && $this.is(":visible") && this.value.length<10){
     alert("phone number required");
} else if(!this.value.length) {
     // alert field empty ?
} else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery has a validation plugin. Does all the heavy lifting for you. It has minimum length validation, plus validations to see if the number is a valid us phone #, valid CC # and many other field types.  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation